# Why is this pattern unreachable?

Tags: rust

```rust
#[allow(dead_code)] 
fn print_grid(empty: (usize,usize), goal: (usize,usize), (w,h): (usize,usize)) {
    for y in 0..h {
        for x in 0..w {
            let s: String = match (x,y) {
                empty => "_".to_string(),
                goal => "G".to_string(),
                (0,0) => "*".to_string(),
                _ => ".".to_string()
            };
            print!("{s} ");
        }
        println!();
    }
}
```

This match statement generates an unreachable pattern warning:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/lib.rs:75:17
   |
74 |                 empty => "_".to_string(),
   |                 ----- matches any value
75 |                 goal => "G".to_string(),
   |                 ^^^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default
```

And indeed, when I use this function, any pattern will lead to "_" being printed.

It may be obvious but I can't figure it out. Is this an error from Rust (I doubt it)? Is there something important I'm missing?

Comment: Does the hint `matches any value` under `empty` help? If not, it might be possible that there should be an issue to make it more prominent (now it is hidden between code lines a little, so might be simply unnoticed).

Comment: @Cerberus Fixed it ! (see answer below). Thx anyway

Comment: I mean, when the error message is unhelpful, Rust team might consider this a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patterns in Rust can only compare against the shape of the data or literal values. So it's possible to pattern match against (for instance) the number `1` since that's a literal in the code, but not against a variable.

```
match (x,y) {
  empty => "_".to_string(),
  goal => "G".to_string(),
  (0,0) => "*".to_string(),
  _ => ".".to_string()
};
```

The names `empty` and `goal` here have *no* relation to the names `empty` and `goal` you already declared. They're new variables shadowing the old ones. So the first pattern will match *anything* and will assign it to a new variable called `empty`.

To compare against variables, use a guard clause.

```
match (x,y) {
  (0,0) => "*".to_string(),
  x if x == empty => "_".to_string(),
  x if x == goal => "G".to_string(),
  _ => ".".to_string()
};
```

Comment: Thank you ! I wonder how I didn't notice this rule in the hours of coding in rust...

Comment: Easy mistake to make. Some languages (Elixir comes to mind) will let you "pin" a variable, so `xyz` is a pattern that binds a variable, but `^xyz` is a pattern that checks for equality. I'm not sure if this has been proposed in Rust in the past, but it would be nice to have.